# Is there a simple way to tweak the momentum/inertia on draggable elements in Framer Motion?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, framer-motion

Sorry if this is a silly question – it feels like it should be simple but I've been searching the Framer Motion docs, Googling, looking for previous Q/A's here, all to no avail.

I've got a draggable motion div, and I simply want to tweak (specifically, lessen) the momentum of the element's movement on drag release.

```
<motion.div drag >{child}</motion>
```

I don't want the element to snap back to its origin point, by the way, which can sort of be controlled with bounceStiffness and bounceDamping, but yeah, that's not really what I'm after. Is there another property/param I can use for this?

I don't know, it just seems like this would be a really common parameter that people would need to tweak, but maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

If anyone comes across this in search of the same answers, I ended up going through the source code and found some properties I hadn't seen mentioned anywhere in the docs.

Add these properties to your motion.div (or whatever draggable element) and tweak as required.

```
dragMomentum={true}
dragTransition={{ timeConstant: 1000, power: 0.1 }}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).